# Is there a way to identify which c++ binaries are changed after compilation/build

Tags: c++, devops

We have unique requirement such that we need to deliver only those binaries and libraries to clients which have undergone any change between last buld and the latest build. So far we had been doing this manually. Is there automated way of doing this on linux cpp builds

Comment: Maybe you can use CMake's file hash function to compare hashes? (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) and then create a script to compare hashes created the previous build for output files to quickly find out which have changed?

Comment: I feel like a bash script could do this pretty easily.

Comment: If binaries created from identical source hashed the same then it wouldn't be too hard of a task to build your own tool, but there is unique per-compile information like build-id that is going to be generated every time an object fine is generated.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a shell script to list files that have been modified since the last build, and copy them to a temp directory? You can use "find" in Linux to look for files that have been modified since a specific date and do something with these files:

find [directory] [type of file] [Time of the last data modification] [action]

For example:

```
find . -type f -newermt '1/5/2022 00:00:00' -exe cp {} /dirToModifiedFiles
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Find will help me in identifying  only list of files which have undergone any change since previous build, and then compiling and delivering only those perticular liberaries. But we need to also identify all the dependent libraries which require rebuilding. That will be taskof another script I guess. Or is there any easier way to do this

Comment: I was thinking more in terms of like rebuilding all the binaries and liberaries and then comparing those aginst previous build, in order to identify which library has changed.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: As for the first comment, you could probably manually identify dependencies once, store it in a file, and write a script that traces the dependencies. For the second comments, it is not clear what you need to do. Rebuilding all the libraries defeats the purpose of what you needed to do in the original post.

Comment: If i rebuild all the libraries and deliver only those ctually changed , it will still meet my requirement from the original post. Only problem is the manual work involved in identifying those dependencies, which will keep varying everytime based on the header.files which have hanged